# Deleting duplicates based on two columns on specific Excel sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I've two excell sheets, with over 100k rows each, on first sheet I've several columns which includes email and phone, on second sheet I only have email and phone column. How can I find and eliminate duplicates with same email and same phone on second sheet compared with first sheet?

Comment: Ok, I've found this, http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28201620/deleting-duplicates-based-on-two-columns-on-specific-excel-sheet were solution provided was to use VLookup
=if(isna(vlookup(sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$100,1,FALSE)), "Not Found", "Found")
The you can filter "Not Found"

But this solution compares first sheet column with two columns on the second sheet.

I need to compare both columns on both sheets, how to change this formula to what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combines your statement into two different column comparisons, and only reports found if both columns are a match:

`=IF(AND(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)),"Found","Not Found")`

Answer (score 0):

I was having some inconsistencies but them I noted that my second sheet had more rows than first one, just changed that on formula and now works like a charm, thanks!